# i have two tables , which have one to many relationship , I am trying to retrieve data by id from both tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

**supplier model**

```
public function supplierlandlines(){
        return $this->HasMany('\App\Supplierlandline');
     }
```

**supplierlandline model**

```
public function suppliers(){
        return $this->BelongsTo('\App\Supplier');
     }
```

**controller**

```
public function show (){
        $suppliers=\App\Supplier::all();
        $supplierlandlines = \App\Supplier::find(1)->supplierlandlines;


    return view('suppliers',compact('suppliers','supplierlandlines'));




    }
```

**view**

```
@foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
                            <tr >


                                <td >{{$supplier->name}}</td>
                                <td >{{$supplier->company}}</td>
                                <td >{{$supplier->address}}</td>
                                <td >{{$supplier->email}}</td>

                                    <ul >
                                        @foreach($supplierlandlines as $supplierlandline)

                                        <li>{{$supplierlandline->landline}}</li>

                                        @endforeach

                                    </ul>
                                </td>

                          </tr>
```

this returns the first supplier's landlines for all the suppliers , I need to return landlines for each supplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Controller:

```
public function show (){
   $suppliers = \App\Supplier::with('supplierlandlines')->all();

    return view('suppliers', ['suppliers' => $suppliers]);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
    <tr >
        <td >{{$supplier->name}}</td>
        <td >{{$supplier->company}}</td>
        <td >{{$supplier->address}}</td>
        <td >{{$supplier->email}}</td>
            <ul >
                @foreach($supplier->supplierlandlines as $supplierlandline)
                    <li>{{$supplierlandline->landline}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```